# Designing an updater with certificate renewal in mind

Tags: digital-signature, code-signing, updates

A program A downloads signed executables and other signed configuration files. Configuration files have a signature appended at the end. To verify their integrity and creator, it uses the public key hardcoded in the program A.

In a couple of years, the certificate that was used to sign the files expires and a new one will be issued. Program A will download the newly updated files, but because it is using the old certificate's public key for validation, it thinks that the files were tampered with.

What is the "right" way for remotely installed programs to identify if an update is safe to apply? Hardcoding the public key is likely to be problematic.

Comment: Is it a certificate with a publicly accessible CA or is it “self signed”? Also, is there a certificate structure or just is there just a flat CERT with key (ea is there a branch & leaf certificate or not)

Comment: it's an DigiCert EV cert with publicly accessible CA. It has a certificate structure.

Comment: So you could consider pinning your certificate supplier as the only one that can supply a new certificate and verify the CERT used with ocsp.

Comment: *"Hardcoding the public key is likely to be problematic."* - why? I.e. why not pin to a specific public key and use this one in the renewed signing certificate too? At the end it depends whom to you want to trust: your own certificates only, anything issued by a trusted CA, ...

Comment: @SteffenUllrich CA says not to do it: https://www.digicert.com/blog/certificate-pinning-what-is-certificate-pinning

Comment: @sanjihan: what is described there is a different use case, namely HPKP where even a short compromise of a web site or header injection might lead to a hacker causing DoS with wrong HPKP headers. But this is not your use case here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I asked digicert support if it is possible to issue a renewed certificate, but make is to that both old and newly signed files are validated with the same public key. They said that is not an option.

Comment: Can’t you just send an update still signed with the old cert with a new cert to trust in it? Like 3/4 into the lifetime of the current cert you request a new one to start updating the app?

Comment: If the app uses a hard-nose public key then it has to contain a self-updater that is able to update the application or at least that part that contains the public key so that you can migrate the accepted key.

Comment: @Robert Is making a simple request to the backend server for the new public key only considered  good practice? Because getting a user to install a full update is near impossible. It is not unusual to be 6 months behind.

Comment: *program A downloads signed executables and other signed configuration files* ... is it possible to use this signed executable and or config files to update program A before it expires?

Comment: What if you sign the new certificate with the old certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what technologies you are using or how the certificates are generated so it's hard to give an answer that is well-targeted for what you are doing, but I would suggest that you construct a *chain of trust*.  You can make a certificate that contains the new public key, then sign it using the old key pair before that key pair expires, and ship the certificate with your executables.  There are, of course, lots of details to figure out to make this be safe and secure.

When Windows announces that an executable has a verified publisher, it usually means that there is a chain of trust from a Trusted Root Certificate on the computer going to a publisher's certificate that was used to sign the software.  The software can hold various certificates in it that the computer then uses to construct a chain of trust.

Answer (score 0):

I would not hardcode the public certificate, but rather use a config file, because updating it is much simpler. Anyway, you are left with 2 common ways:

- if you can be sure of the exact moment of the certificate change, you will have to update your configuration (or you application if the certificate is hardcoded) at that exact time. Any failure in doing so, because either part has added a delay will result if rejecting legitimate files
- or you can accept up to 2 certificates at the same time. In *standart* operation mode, you only use one. At renewal time you add the future certificate between the time it has been issued and the time it is used. And when you are sure the old one should no longer be used, you remove it.

That second way does require 2 changes per certificate renewal (first to add the new one and second to remove the old one) but it is much more tolerant to any delay...